# El siguiente código funciona bien en pantalla grande y en modo responsive no. porque?

Tags: javascript, html, formularios

Tengo en siguiente html que funciona perfecto en una pantalla grande y se ve bien en una pantalla pequeña.
Pero cuando quiero obtener el dato del input con javascript no funcionar sin embargo en la computadora si funciona sin problema.
`

```
        <div class="ps-form--search-mobile" >
            <div class="form-group--nest">
                <input id="buscar" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Buscar producto">
                <button onclick="buscar();"><i class="icon-magnifier"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

javascript

Dentro de la funcon el document.getElementById en modo celular no funciona en pantalla grande captura muy bien el dato del imput.

```
function buscar() {
   var  datos = document.getElementById('buscar').value;
   var text = window.location;
  

console.log(datos);

if (text.pathname=="/buscar") {
 // window.location.reload();


}else{
   window.location.href = "buscar";
   
}

document.cookie = "busqueda="+datos+"; max-age=3600;";
}
```

He ensayado con un codigo jquery y tampoco obtengo una respuesta oportuna en forma responsive

Comment: No existe el "modo responsive", Responsivo es una técnica para ajustar el contenido al tamaño de la pantalla, es irrelevante el dispositivo donde se ejecuta solo importa el tamaño de la pantalla. Si a ti te funciona en el computador pero no en el teléfono móvil, debe ser relacionado con el navegador y su configuración (siempre y cuando el código expuesto sea correcto).

Comment: por casualidad no habrá otro `<input id="buscar"` en un bloque visible sólo en desktop? si es así esta funcionando bien, encuentra el primer input ( que debe estar oculto y vacío )

Comment: Muchas gracias alo malbarez, tenia dos input uno en el  menú dispositivos móvil y otro en el menú de pantalla grande con el mismo id. Aunque estaba en paginas diferentes  se atrofiaban entre ellos mil gracias por su respuesta.